# Remove suffix from filename in Swift

Tags: swift, string, split, suffix

When trying to remove the suffix from a `filename`, I'm only left with the suffix, which is exactly not what I want.

What (how many things) am I doing wrong here:

```
let myTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "demoArt")

let filename = (myTextureAtlas.textureNames.first?.characters.split{$0 == "."}.map(String.init)[1].replacingOccurrences(of: "\'", with: ""))! as String

print(filename)
```

This prints `png` which is the most dull part of the whole thing.

Comment: Use first object `map(String.init)[0]` pass subscript 0 instead of 1, or use `first?` directly `map(String.init).first?`

Comment: What is this doing differently?

Comment: Can you explain "What is this doing differently?"

Comment: Exactly; can you explain how it is that the change you're suggesting actually works?

Comment: btw I copied this line. I have very little idea what it's doing, or how it could possibly split a string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also split the String using componentsSeparatedBy, like this:

```
let fileName = "demoArt.png"
var components = fileName.components(separatedBy: ".")
if components.count > 1 { // If there is a file extension
  components.removeLast()
  return components.joined(separator: ".")
} else {
  return fileName
}
```

To clarify:

```
fileName.components(separatedBy: ".")
```

will return an array made up of "demoArt" and "png".

Comment: I just got this one working in a loop. VERY COOL! This function and its syntax is (to my eyes) much easier to understand, look at and incorporate. Very, VERY cool!

Comment: @Confused, glad it worked for you! Yeah I think it's the simplest way to do this.

Comment: I like this very much. Simple, concise,

Comment: @BartvanKuik, I'd also look at Nirav D's answer below - it doesn't have the same force unwrap as mine.

Comment: This doesn't work if the file name itself also contains periods.

Answer (score 41):

If by suffix you mean path extension, there is a method for this:

```
let filename = "demoArt.png"
let name = (filename as NSString).deletingPathExtension
// name - "demoArt"
```

Answer (score 14):

Some people here seem to overlook that **a filename can have multiple periods in the name** and in that case **only the last period** separates the file extension. So `this.is.a.valid.image.filename.jpg` and stripping the extension should return `this.is.a.valid.image.filename` and not `this` (as two answers here would produce) or anything else in between. The regex answer works correctly but using a regex for that is a bit overkill (probably 10 times slower than using simple string processing). Here's a generic function that works for everyone:

```
func stripFileExtension ( _ filename: String ) -> String {
    var components = filename.components(separatedBy: ".")
    guard components.count > 1 else { return filename }
    components.removeLast()
    return components.joined(separator: ".")
}

print("1: \(stripFileExtension("foo"))")
print("2: \(stripFileExtension("foo.bar"))")
print("3: \(stripFileExtension("foo.bar.foobar"))")
```

Output:

```
foo
foo
foo.bar
```

Answer (score 8):

In iOS Array start with 0 and you want name of the file without extension, so you have split the string using `.`, now the name will store in first object and extension in the second one.

Simple Example

```
let fileName = "demoArt.png"
let name = fileName.characters.split(".").map(String.init).first
```

Comment: argh, so this is a very powerful little piece of code, splitting and storing the name, first part in position[0], second part in position [1]. What's the name of this array? map?

Comment: `split(".")` returns character View and using map function we have created String from it, if you don't use `.first`  then name will be array with two objects.

Comment: ¿Why does your line not need the very confusing:  $0==

Comment: @Confused `characters` will use to iterate through the all the characters of string one by one, if you write `.split { $0 == "." }`, here $0, iterate one by one characters of string and check for `.` but you can also directly use split function like `split(".")`.

Comment: @Confused Also the syntax you are using is used split with closure and i have used it `split()` function.

Comment: argh, got it. I'm going to try incorporate it in a loop to go through an array of textures as per what comes out of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811334/folder-of-images-create-and-fill-skshapenodes-1-of-each and let you know my results...

Comment: GOT IT! Had to make a couple of little changes. Added a force unwrap at end and needed an argument label as per new Swift 3.0:         for name in arrayOfFileNames {
            let fileNameWithoutSuffix = name.characters.split(separator: ".").map(String.init).first!
        print(fileNameWithoutSuffix)
        }

Answer (score 8):

If you don't care what the extension is. This is a simple way.

```
let ss = filename.prefix(upTo: fileName.lastIndex { $0 == "." } ?? fileName.endIndex))
```

You may want to convert resulting substring to String after this. With `String(ss)`

Comment: how does this work? Sorry. I'm a little dense, and need explanations.

Comment: Sorry there was a slight issue with my original code, hopefully the change I made will help understanding. To explain, the prefix function searches a collection, in this case a string, until it finds one matching the character, it returns a substring with all those characters prior to the matched character. The `String(` calls the constructor converting the substring to a regular string.

Comment: If you have asd.asd/asd.es this is a bad answer.

Comment: OK fixed it to handle the case presented by Ariel.

Answer (score 6):

@Confused with Swift 4 you can do this:

```
let fileName = "demoArt.png"
// or on your specific case:
// let fileName = myTextureAtlas.textureNames.first

let name = String(fileName.split(separator: ".").first!)
print(name)
```

Additionally you should also unwrapp `first` but I didn't want to complicate the sample code to solve your problem.

Btw, since I've also needed this recently, if you want to remove a specific suffix you know in advance, you can do something like this:

```
let fileName = "demoArt.png"
let fileNameExtension = ".png"

if fileName.hasSuffix(fileNameExtension) {
    let name = fileName.prefix(fileName.count - fileNameExtension.count)
    print(name)
}
```

Comment: @Moritz, yeah. I did add it because I was getting a warning here, probably because I started with different code. It's fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

How about using `.dropLast(k)` where `k` is the number of characters you drop from the suffix ?

Otherwise for removing extensions from path properly from filename, I insist you to use URL and `.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent`.

Maybe a bit overhead but at least it's a rock solid Apple API.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a Regexp to extract all the part before the last dot like that :

```
let fileName = "test.png"
let pattern  = "^(.*)(\\.[a-zA-Z]+)$"
let regexp = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let extractedName = regexp.stringByReplacingMatches(in: fileName, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, fileName.characters.count), withTemplate: "$1")
print(extractedName) //test
```

Comment: Strewth. Way beyond my stringFu, but very cool to know. I'm sure I'll need it quite soon... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

```
let mp3Files = ["alarm.mp3", "bubbles.mp3", "fanfare.mp3"]
let ringtonsArray = mp3Files.flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: ".").first }
```

Comment: now imagine a `"my.file.mp3"`. Your algorithm, will return `"my"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a new string removing a definite number of characters from the end.

```
   let fileName = "demoArt.png"
   fileName.dropLast(4)
```

This code returns "demoArt"

Comment: Now imagine you have a `.gz` file. Or a `.plan` file...

Comment: I would suggest to always avoid hard-coded stuff like this...

Comment: I was young and naive

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
let stringWithSuffixDropped = fileName.split(separator: ".").dropLast().joined(separator: ".")
```